# Flutter - How to change index of BottomNavigationBar if NavigationBar is not visible?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my setup:

Home.dart

```
final List<Widget> _pages = [
    Screen1(),
    Screen2(),
    Screen3(),
    Screen4(),
  ];

int _selectedPageIndex = 0;

  void _selectPage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedPageIndex = index;
    });}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: _selectedPageIndex != 2
          ? Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
             ...
```

Now when we navigate to `Screen3()` I'm hiding the complete `BottomNavigationBar` and show the Screen in Fullscreen. With a button I want to navigate back to any other position. How to do this? I don't want to use any Routes to close. How can we access  `_selectedPageIndex` or do you have another good idea?

Would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: There are many ways to do it. Define a method called changePageIndex() wich will basically change the _selectedPageIndex vaiable of the class. Now when you are making object of Screen1(), Screen2(), just pass the current instance in the constructor like Screen1(this), in Screen1 class u can manipulate the parent class calling its changePageIndex() method

Comment: More simpler way will be Create a FAB and on tap u change the screen class of the body. Or u can use stack. child1 will hold screen() and child2 u will create buttons which can change child1

Comment: @Epsi95 thank you for commenting, as I'm still pretty new and willing to learn from it, could you provide me an example code from what you described? That would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: keep previous index, needed when go back from full screen page

```
void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _previousIndex = _selectedPageIndex;
      _selectedPageIndex = index;
    });
  }
```

Step 2: pass `refresh()` `callback` to full screen page here is `Setting()`

```
void refresh() {
    setState(() {
      _selectedPageIndex = _previousIndex;
    });
  }

...
case 2:
        {
          print("settings");
          return Settings(
            callback: refresh,
          );
        }
```

Step 3: In full screen page's `Raised Button` call this `callback`

```
RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            widget.callback();
          },
          child: Text("Go back"),
        )
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedPageIndex = 0;
  int _previousIndex = 0;

  void refresh() {
    setState(() {
      _selectedPageIndex = _previousIndex;
    });
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _previousIndex = _selectedPageIndex;
      _selectedPageIndex = index;
    });
  }

  Widget pageCaller(int index) {
    print(index);
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        {
          return Category();
        }
      case 1:
        {
          return Feed();
        }
      case 2:
        {
          print("settings");
          return Settings(
            callback: refresh,
          );
        }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: pageCaller(_selectedPageIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: _selectedPageIndex == 2
          ? null
          : BottomNavigationBar(
              items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  title: Text('Category'),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.business),
                  title: Text('Feed'),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.school),
                  title: Text('Settings'),
                ),
              ],
              currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
              selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
              onTap: _onItemTapped,
            ),
    );
  }
}

class Category extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Category"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Feed extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Feed"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Settings extends StatefulWidget {
  VoidCallback callback;

  Settings({this.callback});

  @override
  _SettingsState createState() => _SettingsState();
}

class _SettingsState extends State<Settings> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        Text("This is setting page"),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            widget.callback();
          },
          child: Text("Go back"),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: great answer, thank you very much! This helps alot.